# How to order by a known id value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to order a select from mysql by using a known id first.

Example:
`$sql = "SELECT id, name, date FROM TABLE ORDER BY "id(10)", id DESC`

Not sure if the above makes sense but what I would like to do is first start ordering by the known id which is 10 which I placed in quotes "id(10)". I know that cannot work as is in the query but it's just to point out what I am trying to do.

If something similar can work I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT id, name, date 
    FROM tbl 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT id, name, date, IF(id = 10, 1, 0) AS sort_field
FROM TABLE
ORDER by sort_field, id DESC
```